# Do we need to catch all exception in a servlet?

Tags: java, exception, servlets, sonarqube

In various code quality scanners, rules are in place that warn about throwing exceptions from within a servlet.

Most particularly "Exceptions should not be thrown from servlet methods":
https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules?open=squid%3AS1989&rule_key=squid%3AS1989

The rule notes it's possible to leak sensitive information to the public, but is that really the case when we've got a proper error page configured in web.xml ?

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Based on a few settings and exception type, that page decides what to show to the public, as well as logging the problem. This gives us a generic way to handle exceptions across the various servlets in the application.

So, my question: is that rule relevant in this case? And if so, what might I be overlooking here?

Comment: What about the other 5xx errors?

Comment: I think all application exceptions are returned at 500 errors. The others are probably done by the server, no? I've never seen it otherwise though, but I might be wrong

Comment: It can also be `<error-page><exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type><location>/error.xhtml</location></error-page>`